# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS won’t boot on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

So I’ve recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 model B with 4Gb of RAM. I used the raspberry Imager to install Ubuntu server 20.04.2 LTS on my 64GB SD card. When I plug the power in, nothing happens I just get a constant red light and nothing on my screen. I’ve tried re-installing Ubuntu but it didn’t change anything. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

I was just able to get the 32 bit version to work using this article:

https://linuxhint.com/install-ubuntu-desktop-20-04-lts-on-raspberry-pi-4/

Instead of creating the wpa_supplicant file I updated using Ethernet.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.